# Wrapping attributes in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, formatting

I am new to WPF and XAML and I've been struggling to find any guidance on correct wrapping for attributes and other long code elements.
In regular C Sharp, I have always limited myself to 100 characters for legibility, and I'd like to continue doing that here.

Here's an example I've written.

```
<!--Folder treeview-->
<TreeView x:Name="FolderView" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--Item Template-->
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding Type, Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Should I be wrapping like this?

```
<TreeView x:Name="FolderView" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

or like this?

```
<TreeView x:Name="FolderView" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

How can I wrap long elements which are in curly brackets? Pressing enter inside brackets in VS results in the misaligned:

```
                <Image Width="20" Margin="3" 
                       Source="{Binding Type, 
                    Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
```

The more familiar way of wrapping in c sharp doesn't compile and requires manual alignment (never a great idea):

```
                <Image Width="20" Margin="3" 
                       Source="
                       {
                            Binding Type,
                            Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}
                       }"/>
```

This is likely a fairly subjective topic, as these things always are, but I'd like to know what some of the preferred styles in the industry are.

Comment: I assume the XAML parser does not allow whitespace between the opening curly brace and the name of the markup extension.

Comment: @KlausGütter seems that way, though I'm not sure whether I should be writing it that way anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the place to discuss about style.

Comment: I see. Any chance you could point me towards some Microsoft guidelines or somewhere where this has been discussed before? I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Line breaks within XML attributes are not very common at all (although technically allowed). Personally, I did not see them in any Microsoft or other examples.